# Put a margin between html table columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am on IE9+ and Firefox/Chrome latest.

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/wmuGH

How can I put a margin between all columns that the table looks like a diagram?

I do not want to use an empty dummy column between the real ones and set their width to fake the margin.

I have played a lot with padding and margin but either the rounded border at top is broken or the background-color of the diagram columns are floating into the new created gap between the columns...

UPDATE:

There should be no gap between the rows.

Just like this:

[image]

Comment: You should put the relevant code inside the question instead of linking to it.

Comment: have you tried the cellspacing & cellpadding properties?

Comment: @Daanvn Relevant code is relative to everyone taking a different approach on the solution.

Comment: @KAsh — This isn't 1997. We have CSS 2 now.

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, but if some day the link breaks then this question will be useless.

Comment: This is true of course but due to SO stupid rules and this is: When I put too much code into a question I have still to write more text which I do not know what to write...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
#responseTable  {
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border-spacing: 4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qLumE/

Comment: I updated my question with a design. Just a margin between columns NOT rows.

Comment: @HelloWorld — See the spec for `border-spacing`, it gives you that flexibility.