# Put a css border on a table with border-space

Tags: html, css

I am using the following HTML and CSS (see it on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/sAeGr)):

```
<table id="responseTable" style="margin-top:10px;"  >
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td><div></div></td>
            <td><div class="emptyCell"></div></td>
            <td><div class="emptyCell"></div></td>
            <td><div class="emptyCell"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5 Min.</td>
            <td class="third">14</td>
            <td class="third">3</td>
            <td class="third">12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15 Min.</td>
            <td class="second">2</td>
            <td class="second">12</td>
            <td class="second">12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&lt; 1 Std.</td>
            <td class="first">2</td>
            <td class="first">5</td>
            <td class="first">12</td>
        </tr>  
        <tr id="labelRow">
            <td> </td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>AD</td>
            <td>VKF</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr id="testsRow">
            <td style="border-top: 2px solid black;">tests</td>
            <td style="border-top: 2px solid black;">5</td>
            <td style="border-top: 2px solid black;">12</td>
            <td style="border-top: 2px solid black;">12</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    font-family:arial;
}

#responseTable {
    border-collapse:separate; 
    border-spacing: 20px 0px;
}

th, td {
    padding: 0;
}

td{
    text-align:center;  
}

tr{
     height:50px;
}

.emptyCell
{
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border-top: gray dashed 2px;
    border-left: gray dashed 2px;
    border-right: gray dashed 2px;

    border-bottom: gray dashed 2px;
    /* margin-bottom:-5px; */

    background-Color:white;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
    width:50px; 

}
tr td:nth-of-type(2)
{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:100px;    
}

tr td:nth-of-type(1)
{
    width:100px;   
}

tr td:nth-of-type(1) ~ td
{
    color:white; 
    border-bottom:white solid 1px;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(2) ~ td
{
    width:40px;    
}

#testsRow td{
  background-color:#99cc66;
  color:#000;
}

#labelRow td{
  background-color:white;
  color:#000;
}

.first {    
background-color: #91B219;
}

.second {    
background-color: #1F8A70;
}

.third {    
background-color: #004358;
}
```

...to set a top border over a table cell. But since I am using `border-spacing` which causes a gap between cells, the top border does not apply over the "gap", so I cannot create a summary line over the cells in `#testsRow`.

I have also thought about the tag `tfoot` whether it could help but still the vertical border space stays...

I have also thought of making the summary footer in an extra table, that way when I use dummy gap/empty columns they are created only for ONE row and not all rows when I would use such columns for the top diagram table.

Or is it possible to use the border-spacing only on `tbody` and not `tfoot` than I would have at least only one table.

Or you have a better idea?

[image: example image of the how the code looks]

Comment: use margin or padding for cells instead of border spacing then your cell borders will stretch from one cell to the other

Comment: Just a little unclear but what you want is that red line that you have shown over the last row, right?

Comment: @tornados the red line should be replaced by a black line so it looks finally.

Comment: @slash197 I can not use padding/margin for cells instead of border spacing because that would revert the changes I gained from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164027/put-a-margin-between-html-table-columns

Comment: What about using a column with colspan=4 and giving it a top border?

Comment: there is a jsfiddle / codePen at the top :)

Comment: I just saw (I'm apparently an idiot, or blind...) XD

Comment: Damn it, SO banned jsfiddle, and now we have codepen taking its place....

Comment: @DavidThomas lets say the first :P nah... I also thought its bad placed... but was lazy...

Comment: @amn Why did SO ban jsfiddle? I just use CodePen thats all. Be free to use jsfiddle.

Comment: @tornados colspan won`t help here because then I can only display one cell value... and I won`t start concat strings with javascript now :P

Comment: Because this is not a programming forum. Questions are intended to add to the existing database to help other people later, and when your fiddles are removed by you for one reason or another (account deletion for one, or jsfiddle.net goes under), the knowledge base gets corrupted because the links that the questions are riddled with will not point anywhere and will thus be invalid. Same applies to pastebin, codepen and the like. This is why you are encouraged to **inline** your code in-place. If it is too long, then all the better - trim it until you reach minimal example.

Comment: @HelloWorld, I meant you could dedicate one row for that top border line. Then you can have your other cells containing values below in another row.

Comment: @tornados sorry but I can not imagine how it should work or look like. Can you change my fiddle please to show the idea?

Comment: @HelloWorld, please you check the fiddle just to get an idea of what I meant.

Comment: @tornados argh... sorry man before I read your message I edited the fiddle... and havent seen your changes. Can your create a fork from my trunk and change that please again?

Comment: @tornados Did you meant something like that: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/sAeGr a row inside the columnSpan-row this looks good but moved down by one row too much :S

Comment: @HelloWorld, yes that's quite what I meant. It will give you a straight line, though you're right about the moving down of the bottom row.

Comment: Wait, there was some mistake. I have now correcting it. See below answer. I've done it in the fiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

I was <strike>am</strike> not able to post the html code here. I've edited the fiddle by the way. Even forked it this time so as to avoid the overwrite like before.

HTML

```
<table id="responseTable" style="margin-top:10px;"  >
  <tbody> 
  <tr>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div class="emptyCell"></div></td>
        <td><div class="emptyCell"></div></td>
        <td><div class="emptyCell"></div></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5 Min.</td>
    <td class="third">14</td>
    <td class="third">3</td>
    <td class="third">12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15 Min.</td>
    <td class="second">2</td>
    <td class="second">12</td>
    <td class="second">12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&lt; 1 Std.</td>
    <td class="first">2</td>
    <td class="first">5</td>
    <td class="first">12</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="labelRow">
    <td> </td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>VKF</td>
  </tr> 
  </tbody>
  <tfoot style="border-collapse:inherit;">
    <tr class="testsRowBorder" style="height:0;">

    <td colspan="4"  style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">

    </td>

    <tr>
      <td>tests</td>
      <td style="color:black;">44</td>
      <td style="color:black;">55</td>
      <td style="color:black;">33</td>
    </tr>

</tr>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
  font-family:arial;
}

#responseTable  {
  border-collapse:separate; 
    border-spacing: 20px 0px;
}

th, td {
    padding: 0;
}

td{
    text-align:center;  
}

tr{
     height:50px;
}

.emptyCell
{
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border-top: gray dashed 2px;
    border-left: gray dashed 2px;
    border-right: gray dashed 2px;

    border-bottom: gray dashed 2px;
    /* margin-bottom:-5px; */

    background-Color:white;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
    width:50px; 

}
tr td:nth-of-type(2)
{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:100px;    
}

tr td:nth-of-type(1)
{
    width:100px;   
}

tr td:nth-of-type(1) ~ td
{
    color:white; 
    border-bottom:white solid 1px;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(2) ~ td
{
    width:40px;    
}

#testsRow td{
  background-color:#99cc66;
  color:#000;
}

#labelRow td{
  background-color:white;
  color:#000;
}

.first {    
background-color: #91B219;
}
.second {    
background-color: #1F8A70;
}
.third {    
background-color: #004358;
}
```

http://codepen.io/tornados/pen/AxBrh

Comment: ok you have used a nested table what I also suggested. But when you do this I would not put it inside the other table very probably because I still have to align the values under the horizontal border according to the values in the vertical diagrams.

Comment: Hmm, Then I guess the nested table could be moved out of the row containing colspan table as another row, not inside a table. But that would again bring a lot of space either below or above. Have a look now. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JAlIm

Comment: please change your fiddle to this its the first tr after the tfoot: <tr class="testsRowBorder" style="height:0;"> and put it into the solution then I mark it as answer for helping me :)

Comment: and remove this from me thats nonsense: style="border-collapse:inherit;" too bad I can not use this sample because I just realized when I change the height of a td it changes also all other td `s height being in the same row :P I knew why I started with css divs pure... or I make instead for one vertical diagram a table with tr-tags having always only one td-tag :D

Comment: Hi @HelloWorld. Not sure if you're still going with this. But I've updated the code above and the fiddle with <tr class="testsRowBorder" style="height:0;">.